# How to instantiate an ASP.net (MVC 5) Session Variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I followed Microsoft's documentation to the best I could understand it, adding this;

```
// Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
        });
```

to ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) and this;

```
app.UseSession();
```

to Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ...

Yet, when I try to access  `HttpContext.Session`  in any action of any controller 
I get a null reference exception.

I'm trying to force instantiate, but can't figure out what to assign. I know HttpContext.Session is an ISession but I have no idea what implements that inteface, and it is absurd if I have to implement it myself for some key value pairs.

What am I doing wrong?

--
note:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state

Comment: Is the app.UseSession() line after app.UseMvc()? If so, can you add more code, since it looks like it is correct from what you show.

Comment: Yes. That was the issue. I read the article Vladimir posted.

Comment: Please don't add answers to questions, nor use [solved] title devices. You're most welcome to add your own answer though, if you wish to add more to the existing accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you need read this [one](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/). In my case it was usefull.

**UPDATED:**

In this case solution was in right order of initilizing services and add their uses. Right order:

```
   1. AddMvc  
   2. AddCaching  
   3. AddSession
   4. UseSession
   5. UseMvc
```

Comment: Adding just a link is a very poor answer. Please extract the main points from the link and this answer will be valid even if the linked article may be offline in the future

Comment: In this case it was the UseSession that has to be before UseMvc

Comment: Just a note, I also edited the initial question to reflect this solution.